# Bypass a nawk snippet if the input file is empty

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have a script which generates several output files and use these output files during runtime.

Following are the some of the files generated by the script: `apple.txt`, `section_fruit_out.csv`, `section_fruit_out_lookup.csv`, `food_lookup.csv`, `section_fruit_lookup.csv`.

I have a code phrase as below:

```
nawk 'FNR == NR && NF!=0 {x[$1] = $1; next;} {FS=OFS=","} FNR>1{if ($2 in x) {($6 = "apple")} } 1' apple.txt section_fruit_out.csv > section_fruit_out_lookup.csv 
nawk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","; } FNR == NR { x[$1] = $2; next; } { if ($7 in x && $6 == "") { $6 = x[$7]; } else if ($6 == "" && $7 != "") { $6 = "TO_BE_DEFINED" } } 1' food_lookup.csv section_fruit_out_lookup.csv  > section_fruit_lookup.csv
```

This code phrase mainly handles the expected job. But the script does not work as expected if the `apple.txt` file is empty (this file is generated by database queries).  If the `apple.txt` file is empty, the output file (`section_fruit_out_lookup.csv`) of the first `nawk` section is also generated empty. Since `section_fruit_out_lookup.csv` is generated empty and it is used by the second `nawk` command, the second `nawk` command also generates an empty output file (`section_fruit_lookup.csv`).

How can I bypass first `nawk` command if the `apple.txt` file is empty and make the second `nawk` command to use `section_fruit_out.csv` file instead of using the file: `section_fruit_out_lookup.csv`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is a `test` function for zero size file.

```
if test -s apple.txt
then 
    ## apple.txt non empty
    code ...
else
    ## file empty
fi
```

Comment: (note that you can't use that approach if `apple.txt` is not a regular file)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of the `NR == FNR` test to test whether you're processing the first file, you could do:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {...} ...' file1 file2
```

But that's a more expensive test, so if `file1` is a regular file, you might as well use [@Archemar's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237107) and not run `awk` at all if the first file is empty.

In cases (not yours) where `file1` and `file2` have to be the same file, you can do:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {...} ...' file1 ./file1
```

Or:

```
awk 'FILENAME == "-" {...} ...' - <file1 file1
```

**An even better approach** (portable and efficient):

```
awk '!file1_processed {...} ...' file1 file1_processed=1 file2
```

If you need that to apply on `./*.txt` for instance, you'd do:

```
set -- ./*.txt
first=$1; shift
awk '!first_processed {...} ...' "$first" first_processed=1 "$@"
```

A GNU `awk`-specific approach:

```
awk 'ARGIND == 1 {...} ...' file1 file2
```