# Can i skip a pattern and also print that pattern along with line by line file comparison using awk?

Tags: awk, file-comparison

I have the code below (please see [Need to understand below awk command to find missing lines in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392722/need-to-understand-below-awk-command-to-find-missing-lines-in-a-file/744316?noredirect=1#comment1415306_744316)):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a)){print}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

Can I add one more condition to skip the comparison of lines if the line starts with `=` (i.e `'$0 ~ /^=/ {print $0}'`) and just print those lines alone as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}(!($0 in a) || /^=/){print}' 1.txt 2.txt
```

The `||` is an OR statement, so this just adds one more condition to your main `if` there, checking if the line starts with a `=`.